# Can I share a component instance across multiple trees in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xstate

I've been creating an API to help manage state machines in React.

It consists of three components:

1. `<StateMachine>`: Receives an [`xstate`](https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate) machine as a prop, and sets up a context for deeper components to use.
2. `<StateView>`: Receives two props: `state` & `children`, and renders its children only if that state is currently active.
3. `<StateControl>`: Receives some arbitrary props - each being an event used to transition the machine - and converts them to transition callbacks to be passed down to its `children` (which is NOT an element, but an `elementType` as determined by `PropTypes`).

Here is a visual representation of what is at play:

[image: State Machine API Visual Diagram]

Using React's context API, I can flexibly switch on/off nodes in the React tree based on the state of the machine. Here's a sample code snippet demonstrating this:

```
const MyMachine = () => 
{
  return (
    <StateMachine machine={sampleMachine}>
      <StateView state="initializing">
        <StateControl onSuccess="success">
          {MySampleInitializer}
        </StateControl>
      </StateView>
      <StateView state="initialized">
        <p>{"App initialized"}</p>
      </StateView>
    </StateMachine>
  );
```

This works great! When the machine is in the "initializing" state, `MySampleInitializer` gets rendered. When initialization is complete, `onSuccess` is called which transitions the machine to "initialized". At this point, the `<p>` gets rendered.

**Now the problem:**

In most situations, each "state view" would render a *different component* (which gets created & mounted when the appropriate state becomes active).

However what if we wanted to apply the machine to a single component only? For example, I have a `<Form>` component which handles the rendering of some form elements, and should receive *different props* depending on the state the form is currently in.

```
const MyFormMachine = () => 
{
  return (
    <StateMachine machine={formMachine}>
      <StateView state="unfilled">
        <StateControl onFill="filled">
          {(props) => <MyForm {...props} disableSubmit/>}
        </StateControl>
      </StateView>
      <StateView state="filled">
        <StateControl onClear="unfilled" onSubmit="submit">
          {(props) => <MyForm {...props}/>}
        </StateControl>
      </StateView>
      <StateView state="submitting">
        <MyForm disableInput disableSubmit showSpinner/>
      </StateView>
    </StateMachine>
  );
```

Using my current API, rendering a `<MyForm>` within each `<StateView>` will cause `<MyForm>` to be re-mounted anytime a state change happens (thereby destroying any internal state associated with it). The DOM nodes themselves will also be re-mounted, which may re-trigger things like `autofocus` (for instance).

I was hoping there may be a way to share the same `<MyForm>` instance across the various "views" such that this re-mounting does not occur. Is this possible? If not, is there an alternative solution which would fit with this API?

Any help greatly appreciated.

**PS:** If the question title is unsuitable, please suggest a change so that this question may more accessible. Thanks

Comment: IMO your situation looks contrived. I don't see any reasonable argument for sharing in comparison with re-mounting. BTW, what do you exactly mean by "internal state" to be persisted? Form focus? Why should it stay the same for different states?

Comment: @hindmost I have updated OP with a code snippet, which should clarify what you asked

Comment: So far, the best solution I've been able to come up with is to store `<MyForm>` props as 'state' and let each view manipulate these values, which then get passed to a single `<MyForm>` component

Comment: Can you try giving each `MyForm` the same `id`?  Probably won't work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the components inside your `StateView` instances are always constructed regardless of whether you are in the correct state or not.

So in your form example, you always have 3 `Form` instances, but only 1 rendered at a time. As you've stated, you can only have 1 `Form` instance in order to maintain state and prevent re-mounting.

When you are passing a conditional component (`MyForm`) into another component (`StateView`), you should always wrap it inside a function.

Your `StateView` class can then only create the `MyForm` instance if you're in the correct state.

You now have only 1 instance at a time (assuming only 1 state is matched at a time), but each `StateView` still has its own instance which isn't shared.

From what I know, you cannot avoid separate instances unless inside the same parent component.

I would change your `StateView` component to handle multiple state checks instead of one. This way, your instances will be reused when the state changes (again, assuming only 1 state is matched at a time).

Your `StateView` construction could look something like this:

```
<StateMachine machine={formMachine}>
  <StateView>
  {{
    "unfilled": () => (
      <StateControl onFill="filled">
        {(props) => <MyForm {...props} disableSubmit/>}
      </StateControl>
    ),
    "filled": () => (
      <StateControl onClear="unfilled" onSubmit="submit">
        {(props) => <MyForm {...props}/>}
      </StateControl>
    ),
    "submitting": () => (
      <StateControl>
        {(props) => <MyForm disableInput disableSubmit showSpinner/>}
      </StateControl>
    )
  }}
  </StateView>
</StateMachine>
```

Note that in order to reuse a component, the component has to be of the same type. I wrapped the 3rd `MyForm` in an empty `StateControl` so that each state constructs a `StateControl`, and therefore the components can be reused.

Also note that if you do have multiple states matched at a time inside a single `StateView`, you can give each `StateControl` a `key` property. The same `key` property value should not be used on two components that may be instantiated at the same time. An easier solution would be to just have separate `StateView` instances, where each one will only match a single state at a time.